# Adding latex to figures from Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, psfrag

I have been using psfrag to add latex to figures for a while.  I make my figures in Inkscape and compile in MikTex using texniccenter.  I switched laptops and installed the latest Inkscape and MikTex and then psfrag stopped working.  I then downgraded Inkscape to this: *Inkscape 0.48.0 r9654*.  To no avail.  Has anyone had problems like this with psfrag? What is the standard way to add latex to our figures?

Here is the code I use to swap latex into my diagrams.    Am I doing anything wrong?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,right=1in,left=1in,bottom=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage[outdir=./images]{epstopdf}

% [font=small,labelfont=bf] Required for specifying captions to tables and figures

\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pstool}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{float}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\label{HasaRelation}
\psfrag{1}{\Huge $hasA$}
\includegraphics[height= 3cm]{images/HasaConstruction.eps}
\caption{something something}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Why do you need `psfrag` if you are doing your figures in inkscape? I would either save them as `pdf+latex` or export them as `tikzpicture` from inkscape.

Comment: Additionally to what @samcarter wrote, you can call LaTeX from within Inkscape if its only small portions of text.

Comment: @samcarter I don't know what you mean.  ARe you saying I can type $\mathcal{X}$ in my figure and then save as pdf+latex and then MikTex will build the diagram and produce the latex?  (likewise with tikzpicture?)

Comment: @Skillmon, are you saying I can compile latex in inkscape and then have a picture with the tex math symbos?

Comment: @user442920 Yes. If you want I can write an answer to show you a short example how this is done.

Comment: @samcarter yes please, I will award it.

Comment: Yes, you can insert the result of a small LaTeX run. If you go into "Extensions -> Render -> LaTeX..." you can insert the document and specify packages to be loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `psfrag` I would simply export the image as `pdf+tex` from inkscape.

For example if your image looks like this in inkscape:

[image]

you can save it as `.pdf` and select the option "omit text in pdf and create latex file" during the export:

[image]

This will produce two files: a pdf with just the red ellipse but without the text and a `.pdf_tex` file that contains the following code:

```
%% Creator: Inkscape inkscape 0.92.2, www.inkscape.org
%% PDF/EPS/PS + LaTeX output extension by Johan Engelen, 2010
%% Accompanies image file 'drawing.pdf' (pdf, eps, ps)
%%
%% To include the image in your LaTeX document, write
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics{<filename>.pdf}
%% To scale the image, write
%%   \def\svgwidth{<desired width>}
%%   \input{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%%  instead of
%%   \includegraphics[width=<desired width>]{<filename>.pdf}
%%
%% Images with a different path to the parent latex file can
%% be accessed with the `import' package (which may need to be
%% installed) using
%%   \usepackage{import}
%% in the preamble, and then including the image with
%%   \import{<path to file>}{<filename>.pdf_tex}
%% Alternatively, one can specify
%%   \graphicspath{{<path to file>/}}
%% 
%% For more information, please see info/svg-inkscape on CTAN:
%%   http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/svg-inkscape
%%
\begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{595.27559055bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.41428571)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength,page=1]{drawing.pdf}}%
    \put(0.30923193,0.68923333){\color[rgb]{1,1,1}\makebox(0,0)[lb]{\smash{$\mathcal{X}$}}}%
  \end{picture}%
\endgroup%
```

(if you need to adjust the colour or position of the text, you can simply edit this file, just make sure you are not overwriting the adjusted file in case you export again from inkscape)

This file can now easily be included in your latex document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\label{HasaRelation}
\def\svgwidth{.3\textwidth}
\input{drawing.pdf_tex}
\caption{something something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

After compiling with pdflatex (or xe/lualtex) the result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: @user442920 You're welcome!

Comment: Does it the same thing to the text included in the figure? (same font and same fontsize once the corresponding pdf is included in tex)

Comment: @Wallflower It will use the font and fontsize of the surrounding document (keep this in mind when designing your image to get the proportions right).

Comment: Great! thank you so much!

Comment: I get the error pdflatex.sty not found and I can't find it only either to download it :( any help please

Comment: @Wallflower Please ask a new question in which you show us exactly what code you tried and your .log file with the full error message.

Comment: done here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680505/error-in-including-svg-figure-to-my-tex-files

Comment: Sorry to disturb you, but how do I get this window? When I click save as I only have the regular extensions (no pdf+latex)

Comment: @Wallflower If you select `.pdf` in the save as dialogue, this will come up as next window

Comment: For your first answer to me, when you said 'the surrounding document' you meant the inkscape document right ? That's in your accepted response you have .3\textwidth?

Comment: @Wallflower No, the text will have the size of the surrounding latex document. You can use the `.3\textwidth` part from my answer to change the size of the included image, but the font size will be taken from the surrounding latex document.

Comment: Understood, thank you so much for your patience!