# Software for high resolution imaging

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, software

I usually use tikz to make figures or some graphics but it is too complicated when I want to add different things in the same image. I would like to know if there is any software to make graphs preserving the LaTeX font like the ones I will put as an example because in TikZ I think it is too complicated. [image] [image]

Comment: You can use https://www.mathcha.io/

Comment: Just so you know if you ask here there will be a lot of people who recommend you to learn TikZ. In any case, just use Latin Modern font to satisfy the "same font" condition, but more complicated things would be difficult (e.g. the `ℝ^{n × n}` part definitely need LaTeX or equivalent to render math).

Comment: You can download and install the Computer Modern (or Latin Modern) fonts and use them in any application. For where to find these fonts, have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55/where-can-i-find-computer-modern-fonts-for-use-in-other-programs-e-g-adobe-ill .

Comment: @Miguel Have a look at inkscape. It allows you to draw complex images and then save them by splitting it into two parts: the image parts can be saved as pdf and the text parts as tex code so the font will match the one from your surrounding document. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469759/36296 for an example