# Error in including svg figure to my tex files

Tags: floats, svg

I am trying to include an svg figure to my .tex file but I end up getting this error.

```
Package svg Error: File '56turns_compar_svg-tex.pdf' missing
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[
11=2pt, % The default document font size, options: 10pt, 11pt, 12pt
%oneside, % Two side (alternating margins) for binding by default, uncomment to switch to one side
english, % ngerman for German
singlespacing, % Single line spacing, alternatives: onehalfspacing or doublespacing
%draft, % Uncomment to enable draft mode (no pictures, no links, overfull hboxes indicated)
%nolistspacing, % If the document is onehalfspacing or doublespacing, uncomment this to set spacing in lists to single
liststotoc, % Uncomment to add the list of figures/tables/etc to the table of contents
toctotoc, % Uncomment to add the main table of contents to the table of contents
parskip, % Uncomment to add space between paragraphs
nohyperref, % Uncomment to not load the hyperref package
headsepline, % Uncomment to get a line under the header
%chapterinoneline, % Uncomment to place the chapter title next to the number on one line
%consistentlayout, % Uncomment to change the layout of the declaration, abstract and acknowledgements pages to match the default layout
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[hidelinks,colorlinks=false,allcolors=false,pdfencoding=auto,psdextra]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,fit,matrix,shapes,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,calc,calligraphy,shadows}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bigdelim}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    {\includesvg{Figures/chap1/56turns_compar.svg}}
    \caption{Results comparison.}
    \label{fig:MvsT}
\end{figure}
          
\end{document}
```

'56turns_compar.svg' is a simple file I have created using svg.

Comment: If you want to use the svg package, you have to enable shell-escape. Please show your log file so we can check if it is enabled.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It is so long and I am limited in terms of wordsin the question. How can I do it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I am actually using both. My bad, I just have been working on this for two days now -deadline in 3 days-. I will delete it if you want

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz here: https://pastebin.com/5ZJ5igSZ

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I use TexStudio

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598924/36296

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz It works! Much obliiged!!!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes it does! Thank you again